# replace string in a file using sed

Tags: linux, sed

I have file with data fields in this format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS but I noticed the export set the Months values to be the same as the minutes value. I want to use sed to replace the Month value for all line to the same value.

I am trying this and it didn't work:

```
sed "s/-[0-9]{2,}-/-08-/g" test.txt
```

Anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: please give sample of input data and the wished filtered result

Comment: example data is "2012-59-30 23:59:00,94933883,-,testing". I would like that to be changed to "2012-08-30 23:59:00,94933883,-,testing"

Comment: Can you edit your post to specify what happened instead of it "working"? Just saying "it didn't work" isn't very helpful. What did you want to happen, and what happened instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/^\(....\)-../\1-09/' < input
```

Input:

```
$ cat input 
2012-52-05 09:52:00
2012-53-05 09:53:00
2012-54-05 09:54:00
```

Output:

```
$ sed 's/^\(....\)-../\1-09/' < input
2012-09-05 09:52:00
2012-09-05 09:53:00
2012-09-05 09:54:00
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]{4})-[0-9]{2}-/\1-08-/' infile
```